# How to create a Date Object with 12-hour time format in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, date, firefox, frontend

I am not able to create a Javascript `Date` object (in Firefox) with 12-hour format time as a parameter to the `Date` constructor. I tried the following way:

`new Date('2021-05-18 04:00 PM+05:30')`

This works perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox and Safari.

Can someone please help in creating a `Date` object without converting it to a 24-hour time format and which would work on all browsers?

Comment: I would first try to dig further behind, where do you get this date format from, is it possible that you can get a Date object or a 24h ISO string before it was converted to a 12h format by some library somewhere? btw, I think everyone should [use 24h format](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7L71i9uv3o).

Comment: The timestamp format is not one of the two supported by ECMA-262 so parsing is implementation dependent. You should parse and format the string manually, a library can help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't seem to be the correct format to create a date object. Since Date uses `Date.parse` internally and implementation can be different in both the browsers. So I think the final resort will be to move back to 24-hour format only or set the hours and values separately. See the note [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> Note: Parsing of strings with Date.parse is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.

.

Firefox does not recognise the string you are sending Since it's not according to the formats it supports.

The formats supported are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#date_time_string_format)